# How to set the value of count down timer on app start

Tags: android, countdown, countdowntimer

Hey there i have a countdown timer which i used to show the user how much time is left in my app. But now i want if timer is running for 1 min and user closes the app after 30 sec and in next 5 sec user again open the app then time should start to run from remaining 25 seconds

```
    CountDownAdapter countDown = new CountDownAdapter(60*1000, 1000);
                countDown.setSourceActivity(MainActivity.this);
                countDown.start();

 public void onCountDownTimer(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        secondsLefts = millisUntilFinished;
        long secondsLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        long hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
        long minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        long seconds = secondsLeft % 60;
       timerText = hours + "h: "+minutes + "m: "+seconds + "s";

        if(timerText.equals("0h: 0m: 1s"))
        {

        }
        timer.setText(timerText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifecycle of an app looks like [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle):

[image: Lifecycle of an app]

So try to store the current remaining time and the exact current timestamp when `onPause()` is called (the user switches to another app). And when the user opens the app again, you need to catch the `onResume()` function. 
Read out the stored timestamp and compare it with the current time. The time difference can now be substracted from the remaining time that you also stored.

There might be a better solution but it would be the easiest way to store the timestamp and remaining time in an XML file.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but your answer to the question is basically the same like mine.